Integrating $\int_{0}^{t}{e^{i\alpha \cos\theta}\cos k\theta \,d\theta}$, especially when $k=0$ and $k=1$

Integrate
$$\int_{0}^{t}{e^{i\alpha \cos\theta}\cos k\theta \,d\theta}$$
where $k\in N_0$, $t \in (0, \pi)$ and $\alpha $ is an arbitrary complex number.
Especially, evaluate the value when $k = 0$ and $k = 1$.

The integral appears in the fundation of 3D lifting surface theory(a theory that describes the reponse to a gust incidence of a annular cascade, like the blade row in the aeroengines), and I think it could be solved analytically with the help of something like induction method. My try is provided here.
Using:
$$\cos k \theta = 2\cos(k - 1)\theta \cos\theta  - \cos(k-2) \theta$$
Denoting the integral as $F_k(\alpha, t)$, we get
$$\begin{align}
F_k(\alpha, t) &= \int_{0}^{t}{e^{i\alpha \cos\theta}2\cos (k-1)\theta\, \cos\theta\, d\theta} - \int_{0}^{t}{e^{i\alpha \cos\theta}\cos (k-2)\theta d\theta} \tag1\\[6pt]
&= \int_{0}^{t}{e^{i\alpha \cos\theta}2\cos (k-1)\theta \,\cos\theta\, d\theta} - F_{k-2}(\alpha, t) \tag2
\end{align}$$
because
$$
\int_{0}^{t}{e^{i\alpha \cos\theta}2\cos (k-1)\theta\, \cos\theta d\theta} = -2i \frac{\partial F_{k-1}(\alpha, t)}{\partial \alpha}
\tag3 $$
then the integral could be written as
$$F_k(\alpha, t) = -2i \frac{\partial F_{k-1}(\alpha, t)}{\partial \alpha} - F_{k-2}(\alpha, t) \tag4$$
This is the recursive relation. Only $F_0(\alpha, t)$ and $F_1(\alpha, t)$ are needed to solve.
$$F_0(\alpha, t) = \int_{0}^{t}{e^{i\alpha \cos\theta}d\theta}\tag{5}$$
$$F_1(\alpha, t) = \int_{0}^{t}{e^{i\alpha \cos\theta}\cos\theta d\theta} = -i\frac{\partial F_0(\alpha, t)}{\partial \alpha} \tag{6}$$
The precise answer is beyond my mathematical ability.

There should be a closed form using this function. Also, a Jacobi Anger expansion could give a simple series expansion. The incomplete Bessel function may work, but it is not well studied. There does not seem to be a simple closed form

I am not sure there is a closed-form solution to your problem, but a solution with an infinite summation can be obtained. I managed to derive a solution containing one infinite and one definite summation. However, it would be nice if someone could check my solution.
Let's define your integral as:
$$I=\int_0^t e^{i \alpha \cos(\theta)} \cos(k \theta) d \theta \tag 1$$
Using Euler's trigonometric identities you can rewrite your integral as:
$$ I = \int_0^t {1 \over 2} e^{{1 \over 2}i \alpha (e^{-i \theta}+e^{i \theta})} (e^{-i k\theta}+e^{i k\theta}) d \theta \tag 2$$
I checked the transformation using wolfram. Next, we use the following substitution:
$$ x=e^{i \theta} \tag 3$$
$$ {dx \over d \theta}=ie^{i \theta}=ix \tag 4$$
$$ {dx \over ix}=d \theta \tag 5$$
$$ -{i \over x}dx=d \theta \tag 6 $$
$$ x^{-1}=e^{-i \theta} \tag 7$$
$$ \theta = 0 \Rightarrow x=1 \tag 8 $$
$$ \theta = t \Rightarrow x=e^{it} \tag 9 $$
$$ {i \alpha \over 2} = a \tag {10}$$
Now we have the integral:
$$ I = -{i \over 2} \int_1^{e^{it}} (x^{-(k+1)}+x^{k-1}) e^{a(x^{-1}+x)}dx \tag{11} $$
We can split this up:
$$ I = -{i \over 2} \Bigg( \int_1^{e^{it}} x^{-(k+1)} e^{a(x^{-1}+x)}dx +
                           \int_1^{e^{it}} x^{k-1}    e^{a(x^{-1}+x)}dx\Bigg ) \tag{12} $$
We can get similar forms of the integrals if we take the following substitution for the second integral:
$$ x = y^{-1} \tag {13}$$
$$ dx = -y^{-2}dy \tag {14}$$
$$ x = 1 \Rightarrow y=1 \tag {15} $$
$$ x = e^{it} \Rightarrow y=e^{-it} \tag {16} $$
So we have:
$$ I = -{i \over 2} \Bigg( \int_1^{e^{it}} x^{-(k+1)} e^{a(x^{-1}+x)}dx -
                           \int_1^{e^{-it}} y^{-(k+1)} e^{a(y^{-1}+y)}dy \Bigg ) \tag{17} $$
Let's just solve now:
$$I_1 = \int_1^{e^{it}} x^{-(k+1)} e^{a(x^{-1}+x)}dx \tag {18}$$
The exponential function has the following Taylor's series:
$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^n\over n!} \tag{19}$$
that allows us to write:
$$I_1 = \int_1^{e^{it}} x^{-(k+1)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty {a^n(x^{-1}+x)^n \over n!}dx \tag{20}$$
$$I_1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{a^n \over n!}\int_1^{e^{it}} x^{-(k+1)}(x^{-1}+x)^ndx \tag{21}$$
We can use the binomial theorem:
$$ (x+y)^n = \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m}x^{n-m}y^m \tag{22} $$
to write:
$$I_1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{a^n \over n!}\int_1^{e^{it}} x^{-(k+1)}{\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m}x^{n-m}x^{-m}}dx \tag{23}$$
$$I_1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{a^n \over n!} {\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} \int_1^{e^{it}} x^{n-2m-k-1}}dx \tag{24}$$
which we can solve:
$$I_1 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{a^n \over n!} {\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} {1 \over n-2m-k}x^{n-2m-k}} \Bigg |_1^{e^{it}} \tag{25}$$
Note that our second integral now becomes:
$$ I_2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{a^n \over n!} {\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} {1 \over n-2m-k}y^{n-2m-k}} \Bigg |_1^{e^{-it}} \tag{26}$$
Now our our solution is:
$$ I = {i\over2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a^n \over n!} {\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} {1 \over n-2m-k}\Bigg( y^{n-2m-k}\Bigg |_1^{e^{-it}}-x^{n-2m-k}\Bigg |_1^{e^{it}}} \Bigg) \tag{27} $$
$$ I = {i\over2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a^n \over n!} {\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} {1 \over n-2m-k}\Bigg( e^{-it(n-2m-k)} -e^{it(n-2m-k)}} \Bigg) \tag{28} $$
which can be simplified using Euler's trigonometric identities to:
$$ I = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{a^n \over n!} \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} {{\sin \big((k+2m-n)t \big)} \over k+2m-n} \tag{29} $$
I used wolfram to check the simplification. Plugging in your constant we are almost finished:
$$ I = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{{\big({i \alpha \over 2}\big)}^n \over n!} \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} {{\sin \big((k+2m-n)t \big)} \over k+2m-n} \tag{30} $$
Since the edge case where $k+2m-n$ is equal to zero exists, we should write our final solution using the sinc function:
$$ I = t\sum_{n=0}^\infty{{\big({i \alpha \over 2}\big)}^n \over n!} \sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} { \mathrm{sinc} \big((k+2m-n)t \big) } \tag{31} $$
Plugging in $k = 0$ or $k = 1$ still does not give a closed-form solution. Though I still hope this solution can help you.
